# How to make a scrollable animated dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am doing a football website.I intended to set a dropdown menu with the following code:

```
<li>
            <a href="#">Team Profile</a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Chelsea</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Man City</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Southampton</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Man Utd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Arsenal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Liverpool</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">West Ham</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newcastle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Leichester</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">QPR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Burnley</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aston Villa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stoke City</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Crystal Palace</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hull City</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sunderland</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tottenham Hotspur</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Everton</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Swansea</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">West Brom</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
```

and I set the flip down animation with the following css code:

```
.myDropDown
{
   height: 50px;
   overflow: auto;
}
.nav ul {
    *zoom:1;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#333;
}
.nav ul:before,.nav ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.nav ul:after {
    clear:both;
}
.nav ul > li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    color:#fff;
    border-left:1px solid #595959;
}
.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#595959;
}
.nav li ul {
    background:#273754;
}
.nav li ul li {
    width:200px;
}
.nav li ul a {
    border:none;
}
.nav li ul a:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.nav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:36px;
    z-index:1;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(400) rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 0;
    -webkit-transition:350ms;
    -moz-transition:350ms;
    -o-transition:350ms;
    transition:350ms;
}
.nav ul > li:hover ul {
    max-height:1000px;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(400) rotate3d(0,0,0,0);
}
*                                   { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body                                { font: 15px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; } 
html                                { overflow-y: scroll; }
#page-wrap                          { width: 720px; margin: 25px auto; } 
p                                   { margin: 0 0 8px 0; }
a                                   { text-decoration: none; }
img                                 { vertical-align: middle; }
a img                               { border: 0; 180}
ul                                  { list-style: none; }
h1                                  { margin: 0 0 10px 0; }

/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/
ul.dropdown                         { position: relative; width: 100%; }
ul.dropdown li                      { font-weight: bold; float: left; width: 180px; background: #ccc; position: relative; }
ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: #000; }
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; padding: 20px 8px; color: #222; position: relative; z-index: 2000; }
ul.dropdown li a:hover,
ul.dropdown li a.hover              { background: #F3D673; position: relative; }


/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/
ul.dropdown ul                      { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 180px; z-index: 1000; }
ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #f6f6f6; color: #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
ul.dropdown ul li a                 { display: block; background: #eee !important; } 
ul.dropdown ul li a:hover           { display: block; background: #F3D673 !important; } 
.FixedHeightContainer
{
  float:right;
  height: 250px;
  width:250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.Content
{

}
```

but my dropdown is too long.So,i decided to make a scrollable one.So, I added this code.

```
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But then,my menu is not scrollable unless I use this code and this flip down animation is gone.

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Scrollable Menu <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add overflow-y: auto or scroll to have it scrolling in vertical direction. You just disabled horizontal scrolling. So the proper CSS would be

```
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Hope that helps. Have fun.

Comment: thank you for your help.But it still can't work. @benjaminberger

Comment: Or can you send me a fully modified code to my email(ericwatson0816@gmail.com).Thanks! @benjaminberger

Comment: then make height: 200px just to test instead of height: auto

Comment: oh sorry, i now see the problem xD ... add into the first <ul> of your code class="scrollable-menu" so it looks like <ul class="scrollable-menu">

Comment: I check a website and it say "Because it is positioned to the left there is no chance of it creating scroll bars as it may do if positioned to the right".I am not sure what does that mean.You can check the website at http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/nicer-navigation-with-css-transitions-part-2. @benjaminberger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this in `.dropdown-menu`

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top;
transform-origin: top;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
display: block;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
```

And this is all in `.open>.dropdown-menu`

```
display: block;
-webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
transform: scale(1, 1);
opacity: 1;
```